# Check NSError code in swift

Tags: swift, core-motion, nserror

I'm trying to check the error code value in Swift, and find myself a bit confused by the new struct types and conversions.

What I want to do is simply take an NSError object passed in a handler closure and check its code type by comparing it to a value stored in a CMError struct. In Objective-C I would simply write

```
[pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:now toDate:now withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {
    BOOL isAuthorized = (error.code != CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized);
}];
```

In Swift, when I write what I expect to be the equivalent

```
pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(now, toDate: now) {(data:CMPedometerData!, error:NSError!) in
    let isAuthorised:Bool = (error.code != CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized)
}
```

I get the error *Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments*. This points to a type cast error. And indeed `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized` is of type `CMError`, which is a Swift struct. And I can't seem to convert between this `CMError` type and the `Int` type that is that of `error.code`.

So how can I check my error code?

---

#### Note 1

If I try to decompose and explicitly cast:

```
let errorCode:Int = (CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized as Int)
let isAuthorized:Bool = (error.code != errorCode)
```

I get the absurd error message *Cannot convert the expression's type 'Int' to type 'Int'*.

---

#### Note 2

Documentations says `CMError` is defined as

```
struct CMError {
    init(_ value: CUnsignedInt)
    var value: CUnsignedInt
}
```

in Swift. In Objective-C it is defined as

```
typedef enum {
   CMErrorNULL = 100,
   CMErrorDeviceRequiresMovement,
   CMErrorTrueNorthNotAvailable,
   CMErrorUnknown,
   CMErrorMotionActivityNotAvailable,
   CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized,
   CMErrorMotionActivityNotEntitled,
   CMErrorInvalidParameter
} CMError;
```

Comment: Since its an `enum` in ObjC, have you tried `CMError.MotionActivityNotAuthorized`?

Comment: I tried. It says *'CMError.Type' does not have a member named 'MotionActivityNotAuthorized'*.

Comment: It seems to me that since they didn't "modernize" their ObjC enum with `NS_ENUM`, the objc->swift translator didn't translate the enum properly and ended up with a `struct`...might be worth a bug report unless someone figures out why

Comment: Yes I suspected a bug too, but I thought it more probable that I just missed something. If nobody figures out what's wrong, I'll file a bug report, providing this question as a reference.

Comment: I looked at the iOS 8 API diffs and CMError was not in the Core Motion section, seems like the core motion team was lazy or had no idea of swift :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jack Wu's comments are right — this looks like a non-modernized enum, and [filing a bug about that](http://bugreport.apple.com) would be a great idea. In the meantime...

Command-click a `CMError` declaration in a Swift file and you'll get the Swift definition of both the type and the related constants. `CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized` and friends aren't a subtype of `Int`, they're instances of the `CMError` struct, which contains an integer `value`. That value is a `CUnsignedInt`, and Swift doesn't automatically convert that to a signed `Int` for you — part of Swift being a "safe" language is avoiding situations where implicit type conversions can lead to over/underflows that cause [bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Security_ramifications).

So, your query should look something like this:

```
pedometer.queryPedometerDataFromDate(now, toDate: now) { data, error in
    let isAuthorized = (error.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized.value))
}
```

(Also slimmed the code a bit to use type inference.)

Comment: Thanks rickster! I had already tried to cast the `CUnsignedInt` to `Int`, because of that type difference. What I didn't realise was that it was not a cast that was needed but a conversion. Also, I missed the .value property.

Comment: Yup. A good thing to remember: `as` is not a "cast" like in C, but specifically a "downcast". It only lets you treat a value of a general type as a more specific type. Any other type conversion, even between types that look related, uses initializer syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

in **Swift 4.0** you have option to of `CMPedometer.authorizationStatus()` which makes your life a bit easier :)
Here is what I would do, first check version if it is **iOS 11+**, we can use this method, otherwise we use the error parsing method:

```
CMPedometer().queryPedometerData(from: Date(), to: Date()) { (_, error) in

    let isAuthorised: Bool = {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            return CMPedometer.authorizationStatus() == .authorized
        } else {
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                return error.code != Int(CMErrorMotionActivityNotAuthorized.rawValue)
            } else { return true }
        }
    }()


    if isAuthorised {
       // do your stuff
    }

}
```